# Is a Data Stream a Sequence of Memory Addresses like an Array?

Tags: sockets, memory, stream, hardware

I've read a lot of books and articles mentioning data streams, which I've used mostly in Java, and none of them really mention exactly what a data stream is under the hood. Is it data aligned in memory consecutively as bytes? 
Bonus question: What about a socket? How is it represented in memory exactly and how is it connected to a hardware input/output?

Answer (score 1):

A Java stream is an abstraction: just something that you can read from or write to. It is usually backed by an external resource such as a file or a socket. For gory details of each stream, and there are dozens, see the source code. The only two streams that really accord with your description 'sequence of memory addresses' are `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream.`

A socket is an endpoint of a communication. Internally it is a data structure in the kernel, and it is 'connected' to a network protocol stack which in turn is connected to one or more network interface cards (NICs).